# Jquery form reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, tokenize

I have the following function that should reset a part of a form:

```
function changeForm(sel) {
    var arr = {
       "High-School Student": "hs",
       "University Student": "us"
    };
    $('#' + arr[sel]).show();
    delete arr[sel];
    $.each(arr, function (key, value) {
       var div = '#' + value;
       $(div).hide();
       $(div + ' :input').each(function () {
           $(this).val('');
       });
    });
}
```

Based on an input in another field I show the div with the fields relevant to it and reset all other that are not relevant. Some fields have a name of an array type :`name="field_name[]"`. The problem is that for those fields `$(this).val('');` does not unselect the selected properties. The field of this type is multiselect and uses http://zellerda.com/projects/tokenize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the component generates UL instead of input, and the only input element within your tag is an input with 'TokenSearch' class

```
$.each(arr, function (key, value) {
   var div = '#' + value;
   $(div).hide();
   $(div + ' :input').val('');
   $(div + ' .Token').remove();
});
```

Comment: This does remove the tag but the option still stayed selected so `$(div + ' .Close').trigger('click');` triggers the plugin remove event. Thank you for your help !!

Comment: you'r right. mixing the answers will help: `$(div + ' .Close').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a function with this plugins to reset a field, but my workaround is to trigger a click on each close :

assuming this HTML :

```
<div class="tokenize-sample Tokenize" id="tk1">
    <ul class="TokensContainer">
        <li class="Token" data-value="CH"><a class="Close">×</a><span>Switzerland</span></li>
        <li class="Token" data-value="FR"><a class="Close">×</a><span>France</span></li>
        <li class="Token" data-value="DE"><a class="Close">×</a><span>Germany</span></li>
        <li class="TokenSearch"><input size="5"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="Dropdown" style="display: none;"></ul>
</div>
```

I'll execute this js:

```
$("#tk1 .Token .Close").trigger( "click" );
```